# Create a custom Spinner

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to customize the MvxSpinner to add some additional controls, here is my code:

```
public class ChamSpinner : LinearLayout
{
    public Spinner Spinner{ get; private set; }

    public EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs> ItemSelected;

    public ChamSpinner (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : this (context, attrs, new ChamSpinnerAdapter (context))
    {

    }

    public ChamSpinner (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapter adapter) : base (context, attrs)
    {
        ((Activity)Context).LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ChamSpinnerLayout, this);
        Spinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.ChamSpinnerSpinner);
        int itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId (context, attrs);
        int dropDownItemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadDropDownListItemTemplateId (context, attrs);
        adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
        adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId = dropDownItemTemplateId;
        Adapter = adapter;
        SetupHandleItemSelected ();
    }

    public new IMvxAdapter Adapter
    {
        get { return Spinner.Adapter as IMvxAdapter; }
        set
        {
            var existing = Adapter;
            if (existing == value)
                return;

            if (existing != null && value != null)
            {
                value.ItemsSource = existing.ItemsSource;
                value.ItemTemplateId = existing.ItemTemplateId;
            }

            Spinner.Adapter = value;
        }
    }

    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return Adapter.ItemsSource;
        }
        set
        {
            Adapter.ItemsSource = value;
        }
    }

    public int ItemTemplateId
    {
        get { return Adapter.ItemTemplateId; }
        set { Adapter.ItemTemplateId = value; }
    }

    public int DropDownItemTemplateId
    {
        get { return Adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId; }
        set { Adapter.DropDownItemTemplateId = value; }
    }

    public ICommand HandleItemSelected { get; set; }

    private void SetupHandleItemSelected ()
    {
        Spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var position = args.Position;
            HandleSelected (position);
            if (ItemSelected != null)
                ItemSelected (sender, args);
        };
    }

    protected virtual void HandleSelected (int position)
    {
        var item = Adapter.GetRawItem (position);
        if (this.HandleItemSelected == null
            || item == null
            || !this.HandleItemSelected.CanExecute (item))
            return;

        this.HandleItemSelected.Execute (item);

    }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
<cross.android.ChamSpinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/myspinneritemdropdown"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/myspinneritem"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItemsSource; SelectedItem MyItem; Mode TwoWay" />
```

The spinner is always empty, I tried to add a custom binding on ItemsSource property but the result stilll the same. 
How can I do to show my items in my spinner?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't see any obvious issues in your approach. So maybe the problem is in the adapter or the view model. Some debug approaches: Does the ItemsSource ever get set? Is it set with a valid list? Is there any trace output during binding? Does your ChamSpinner show items if you use it with a standard MvxAdapter and a simple ViewModel list like in the MvxSpinner samples in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_Spinner.axml#L22 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this error in my log

**MvxBind:Error: 32,12 View type not found - cross.android.ChamSpinner**

My custom control is in another assembly so I added it to MvvmCross View assemblies is my Setup class like this

```
protected override IList<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies
    {
        get
        {
            var assemblies = base.AndroidViewAssemblies;
            assemblies.Add(typeof(ChamSpinner).Assembly);
            return assemblies;
        }
    }
```

Thank you Stuart for your advices and for your great Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `BindingInflate` instead of `Inflate` should fix it or even points you in the right direction. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/BindingContext/IMvxAndroidBindingContext.cs

```
((IMvxBindingContextOwner)Context).BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ChamSpinnerLayout, this);
```

Comment: you mean ((IMvxBindingContextOwner)Context).BindingInflate (Resource.Layout.ChamSpinnerLayout, this); because your code give a cast exception. The result still the same :(